# jQuery Masonry and isotope - height

Tags: jquery-masonry

I need to show a hidden div that is attached to a `.box` div , my masonry code is

```
$(function(){

var $container = $('.content');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.box',
    isAnimated : true,
    isResizable : true,

  });
});

});
```

Its loads a boxes with images and text , but when i want to show a specified DIV
Masonry want move in height , so my hidden div is showing behind a .box div

```
$('.commentopen').live("click",function()
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
$("#commentbox"+ID).fadeIn('slow');
return false;
});
```

Any ideas how to extend a height in the same window with out reloading
i tries masonry `.reload` or `.reloadItems` but with no luck , i think because of `.imagesLoaded` function

Here a visual explanation [image]

Comment: Impossible to understand your question. You got an online sandbox or jsfiddle to look at so one can understand the problem?

Comment: i updated a post, let me know please if you still dont get it .. http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/9346/91748713.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can understand is that when a "hidden" div is shown, your Isotope layout does not react correctly (repositioning the other elements when the height grows). So, maybe [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/26vBP/) is of some help. If you'd post a link to your sandbox or provide a jsfiddle yourself, it'd be easier to debug. You seem to also load large images via imagesLoaded, so if that's not correctly implemented, it could also play a role.